# R Script for KNN algorithm to run on Tableau

Tags: r, machine-learning, tableau-api, knn

I have been writing R script to integrate with tableau. When I try to run KNN using R's dbscan package, it throws the error: K must be greater than 1 and less than the number of samples.

```
SCRIPT_REAL('
library(dbscan);
lof(as.matrix(data.frame(x= .arg1, y= .arg2)), k= 6)
',
SUM([Measure 1]),
SUM([Measure 2]),
)
```

Comment: ... So, what is your question?

Comment: why the tag `ML` ?

Comment: Scripts throws an error and I cannot debug it